# Social Interaction Tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, social-media

Since a few days now the Google + button is being tracked and shown in our Google Analytics account, [which you can find here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html). There is also a solution to track Twitter, Facebook, ... but can't seem to get it to work, [which you can find here](http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/tracking/javascript/v5/social/twitter_js_async.html). Except putting the JavaScript Source Code in the header, do we need to do something else as well?

Comment: Do you want to give us the link to your page so we can check that the Javascript has been put in properly?

Comment: The jacascript is in an external file which is linked in the head. You can check it at http://www.paulolyslager.com. Thanks!

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Actually, because this is probably a coding problem, I'm moving flagging that it should go to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow?
The problem is that the shares, likes, tweets, ... don´t show up in Google Analytics underneath the social section.

Comment: everythings seems to be working now. I had the help of a javascript wizard who improved the async code. Have a look at the footer for the correct and very short code. Everything is loaded asynchronous as it should!

Answer (score 2):

The Like button in your website header seems to be tracking correctly. The following _utm.gif request is being made:

> `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?`
>   `utmwv=5.1.1&utms=3&utmn=902823811&utmhn=www.paulolyslager.com`
>   `&utmt=social&utmsn=facebook&utmsa=like`
>   `&utmsid=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages...`

The links in the social bar on the left-side of each post will *not* be tracked, because the social actions script is designed to hook into specific events raised by Twitter and Facebook. These events are not called by the share actions in he social bar.

**Edit:** the Like buttons for each post on the homepage are working also. Is this issue resolved?

**Update:** The Social Bar to the left of your articles won't work, because they are coded differently to the Google examples and use different hooks. The Like button at the end of each post, just above the 'About the Author' section, does work, because it is a standard Like button.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems to be working now on the homepage but I have no clue howecome it's not working in my articles. The call for the javascript is done in the footer. So if this works for the homepage, it should be working for the article pages as well.

Comment: Hi @Paul Olyslager, see my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Did you follow Google's guide for configuring [Social Interaction Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did follow the instructions but they forgot to mention that you actually should run the functions afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a far easier, more comprehensive solution for this: http://penguininitiatives.com/track-social-shares-addthis-widget-google-analytics/

Comment: Is it possible to provide a summary of the linked answer? Link only answers aren't particularly helpful if/when the link expires.